# C# Array not clearing in listbox

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

I'm new to programming, and have trouble clearing my listbox to how I want. What happens is that the user is able to enter a value, and this will be stored to an array, which will then be added to a listbox. The user can clear both array/listbox at anytime. However after entering a value e.g. 123 and being displayed on the listbox, then using the clear button. Then again entering another value e.g. 555, instead of 555 being the first number in the lisbox it is: 0, 155. If I again clear then add another number e.g. 1123, output is: 0, 0, 1123. etc. I seem to have cleared only the previous elements and just placing the number to the next index. How do I empty the array/listbox so that I only add numbers to the first index and not get 0000...N displaying in my listbox.

**Button to Clear:**

```
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Array.Clear(numArray, 0, numArray.Length);
        lstHoldValue.Items.Clear();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be that you are not resetting the index value to 0 when clear is clicked. I think in the code which clears the numArray, you setting the values to 0 or you are creating another array, but remember index will still be whatever it was before clearing. If not then post your clearing code and I can help.

I just saw your clearing code and that is exactly the reason. Add this to your clear code:

```
this.index = 0;
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked. Read this thread for how and why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks and its Done :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `Add()` method you can use `Insert(Int32, Object)` method to insert the item in a specific index like

```
lstHoldValue.Items.Insert(0, numArray[i]);
```

Best would be to re-bind the listbox with your new array contents

```
lstHoldValue.DataSource = numArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.Clear` method only resets the values to their default values (0 in the case of integers).

A quick way to clear an array is to reinitialize it, i.e `numArray = new int[10]`

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried replacing the Array.clear with numArray = new int[10] however still get those 0s appearing.

Comment: After re-initializing do you re-bind the array to the list box as in Rahul's answer?

Comment: When I try to use re-bind I get an "System.ArgumentException" error

Comment: Do you reset the "this.index = 0" when clearing the array?

Comment: Yeah, sorry its not just working, but appreciate the help!

Comment: @ Francois du Plessis You we're correct I needed to set my Index to 0. Thank you both soo much for you're help :)